# Will my french drain clog/erode my soil if the pipe has holes on top?

Tags: water, drainage, french-drain

Yesterday, I bought some piping at Home Depot for my french drain project. The solid pipe looked good with the proper alignment of holes. However, I needed flexible piping due to the nature of my project so I got a 4" corrugated pipe. The issue is, the corrugated pipe I bought has holes all around its radius.

I am some what concerned because I know that there are supposed to be two hole near the bottom, but having holes facing up is not recommended.

Will having holes facing up (as well as down) cause me issues such as clogs and soil erosion?

Also, I've seen conflicting messages on whether I should wrap the pipe in a mesh, any opinions on that?

Additional Details:

*Will be a shallow pipe as I just need to redirect surface flow.

*The pipe will run a short length: <20'

*I am planning on using crushed rock on the bottom/sides

Comment: You should be backfilling with crushed rock, soil in direct contact with the pipe will clog the openings of either type.

Comment: I was planning on using crushed rock on the bottom and sides. I was going to avoid it on top since I hear that can damage the pipe, does this sound good?

Comment: I've had to install multiple french drains and even dig some of them back up for mole damage. Rock on top of the pipe has never been an issue. The weight of wet soil will crush a pipe if it's installed wrong and will eventually infiltrate into the rock and plug the pipe if you backfill with it.

Comment: @Fiasco Labs, you seem to be knowledgeable on this topic, let me invite you to post an answer if you can find the time....

Comment: IMPE, return the flexible pipe and buy enough fittings to get the job done with solid pipe. If you go ahead with the corrugated that has holes all over, use fabric, it will buy you some time.

Comment: Another person who seems to know the answer but has written it in the comments... :P :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it will fill in.  My house had a 4" PVC pipe from the foundation to the septic tank, about 10 to 15 feet away.  Apparently, a plumber was out probing for the pipe with a steel rod (standard tool for this), and pierced the pipe without realizing it.  The pipe eventually filled in, and I had a whole lot of digging to do to fix it.